# How do I start KeePass2 (portable) from Nautilus in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: nautilus, mono, keepass

I have KeePass2 installed on a USB flash drive. In Ubuntu 12.04 all I had to do to start is was right click KeePass.exe and select Open With Mono Runtime. In 13.04 I only have the options of opening with Archive Manager or Wine. I have mono installed and can start KeePass from the command line with either:

```
KeePass.exe
```

or

```
mono KeePass.exe
```

I can't start KeePass from a script on the flash drive because it is not possible to make it executable.

Comment: is wine installed? if so set exe files to open with wine

Comment: Wine is installed, but does not work with KeePass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is functionality that was removed from versions of Ubuntu @ 11.10 and beyond. The 'Add' for adding a custom opener no longer exists. If you would like to do this open a terminal and change to your KeePass directory.

Then type:

```
mimeopen -d KeePass.exe
```

You will see that there will be options asking what you want the default open to be, you will select the number that has the option 'Other' and when prompted:

```
mono %f
```

This should allow it into the Open With list. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. That worked. In my case it wasn't mono but mplayer. Shame on Ubuntu for removing the old method and not providing a easy way to do this.